# Why are these Unicode characters not printed although I set my environment to UTF8?

Tags: c, linux, unicode

How to print some Unicode characters?  Although I set UTF-8 encoding, I'm not able to print it. I am getting Unicode characters in hex as (c2 82 c2 81 c2 80 0) in a continuous stream of bytes. But when I tried to print its Unicode character by pointing a character pointer at beginning, it's not printing.  Why?

```
   char s[]={0xc2,0x82,0xc2,0x81,0xc2,0x80,0x00};
   printf("%s",s);
```

Using C in a Linux environment.

Comment: Your `char s[]` provided here does not end with a zero character (`'\0'`), so `printf` cannot work : it will be printing garbage until it finds a zero character or will coredump.

Comment: i did but program is not printing any characters

Comment: Is your terminal configured to use UTF-8?  If not, it will probably be using 8859-1 or 8859-15 or something similar, and will interpret the bytes according to that code set.

Comment: What is the output of `locale` on your terminal? Validate against that and let us know.

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial  http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/unicode.html

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I set character encoding as utf8 in terminal

Comment: Only graphic characters can be displayed. By definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't see much even if your terminal is configured to work with UTF-8 because the characters you are 'displaying' are:

```
0xC2 0x82 = U+0082
0xC2 0x81 = U+0081
0xC2 0x80 = U+0080
```

These are control-characters from the C1 set.  I have a data file which documents:

```
# C1 Controls (0x80 - 0x9F) are from ISO/IEC 6429:1992
# It does not define names for 80, 81, or 99.

80 U+0080
81 U+0081
82 U+0082 BPH BREAK PERMITTED HERE
```

So you don't see anything because you aren't displaying any graphic characters.  If you change your 0x82 to 0xA2, for example (and 0x81 to 0xA1, and 0x80 to 0xA0), then you'll be more likely to get some visible output:

```
0xC2 0xA2 = U+00A2
0xC2 0xA1 = U+00A1
0xC2 0xA0 = U+00A0

A0 U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE
A1 U+00A1 INVERTED EXCLAMATION MARK
A2 U+00A2 CENT SIGN

$ ./x
¢¡ 
$
```

And if you're really good, you can see the no-break space after the inverted exclamation mark¡

Comment: They represent control characters; they don't represent anything visible, any more than a newline character represents anything visible. (Although you can see the side effect of displaying a newline because the cursor changes position to the start of a newline, you can't see the character itself.)  Not all valid characters are visible.  There's a zero-width non-breaking space, for example; you can't spot that on terminal!

Comment: Other than the common white space ones CR, LF, or tab, control characters do not have any semantics assigned by the Unicode Standard.

Comment: The basic control characters are U+0000..U+001F, U+007F (these are the ASCII and 8859-1 control characters), plus U+0080..U+009F (the C1 controls).  If you want more precision, you probably need to look up the General Category of the character (see Chapter 4 of the [Unicode](http://unicode.org/) standard); control characters have the general category `gc=Cc` (Other, Control).

Answer (score 0):

`0xc282c281c280` is a single integer.  You want to initialise the array with a sequence: `char s[] = { 0xc2, 0x82, 0xc2, 0x81, 0xc2, 0x80, 0x00 };`